# why does response()->download($url); gives file does not exist?

Tags: php, laravel, download

Controller code

```
   $url = Storage::url($file->url);
   if ($url) {
     return response()->download($url);
   }
```

Response is

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
> The file "http://localhost/hamimg/V81QGAOl.zip" does not exist

Comment: It clearly says file not found. So the path is incorrect.

Comment: no when i copy paste the does not exists url in the browser it downloads the file so why is that @nice_dev

Comment: `response()->download()` expects a file path. You should probably just use [`Storage::download`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#downloading-files) instead.

Comment: @JomitJose In any file download, you give the file path, you are hitting the URL which is incorrect. If you wish to do it via URL, do `return Redirect::to('http://localhost/hamimg/V81QGAOl.zip');` with `use Redirect;` at the top.

Comment: the problem was fixed i just put the url in the anchor tag so it lets the file to be downloaded into the system was so easy why didnt i think of it earlier my bad but thanks for the answers that you guys have provided @Jeto